# Imperial to Metric Tap Thread Adapter

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, taps

We had been using this basin shower head attachment happily for a while, until a plumber came to replace the taps due to a leakage. The new taps (like the old ones) happen to be a pair of hot and cold non-mixer British/Irish taps but (unlike the old ones) with a smaller diameter, and here's the problem! The shower head attachment does not fit the tap anymore.

I've been to almost all local DIY stores, asking for an adapter, but they have no clue where I can find such a thing!

The diameter of the new tap is 1/2", and the shower head attachment has the two M22 internal, and M24 external threads.

We previously had fit M24 thread by just pushing and squeezing the tap head **into** it (which is possibly unlike the intended use), but that was fitting the tap perfectly well and it was functioning as expected.

Could you advise me what/where to look for to find an adapter/solution to this problem?

P.S. We cannot replace the taps again, because we've rented this place and the landlord doesn't care about our shower head attachment.

As you can see in images below (`A1` & `A2`), when you turn on the tap, the water comes down as expected normally; now if you press the button on the shower head, it'll disconnect the water running down to the basin through the tap, and will direct it to the hose and the shower head.

What he had previously done was to squeeze the tap into the `M24` head on picture `D` and that was working; but now I need some adapter that will allow attaching either of these to a 1/2" thread.

In case you need to learn more about the details of this product, you can see the manual [here](http://www.lidl-service.com/static/72766421/96298_EN_SV.pdf).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: our previous tap]

[image: our current tap; the diameter of the black area is 1/2"]

Comment: How do you manage the water temperature of the shower head when it is only connected to one faucet of a dual faucet (hot & cold) sink?

Comment: @MichaelKaras Good question in 21st century! I cannot, because I live in Ireland, and no one ever has happened to question the point of having non-mixer taps yet. However the hot tap never happens to get too hot, so that can give you a decent temperature.

Comment: Is this the same Hand shower that is on dx?
http://www.dx.com/p/phasat-a501-bidet-spray-gun-shower-head-silver-310639

Im asking because I want to buy this one:
http://www.dx.com/p/phasat-4107-brass-washing-gun-golden-315875

but Im not sure about which thread they use. Do you know?

Comment: Please see also this question:
http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/57772/pipe-thread-in-switzerland

Comment: @Mr.Roland this one is from Lidl, but pretty much the same. If you look closely to my picture, this tap is a cold-only tap from the past that exists in Ireland and some parts of the UK! I don't think you'd have an issue with it if you're using it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Can you make this adapter work?

[image]

This one converts a male 1/2 inch thread to an M22 size. You can see it for sale [at this web site](http://www.bluaqua.com/epages/64003794.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/64003794/Products/10744).

Comment: Hmm, I showed this to another store and they said I cannot find it! That website seems a bot pricy with the postage and stuff. Odd that Amazon nor ebay have it.

Comment: @Neeku - Well the web site is for some water filter company. They may very well have had this made special to fulfill a need they have seen come up for their customers. In your case it may come down to weighing the cost of the adapter against the price of replacing your shower unit entirely or the cost of not having use of the shower unit at all.

Comment: Yeah, you're right Michael. If it were up to me, I'd spend as much as possible to doom the non mixer taps in 2015, but unfortunately I dob't have enough privileges here to do so and I hate spare costs to bring these non standard old stuff to the basic standard level, but no choice!xD </rant>!