# Is There a DIY Way of Fitting This Attachment to My Bathroom Tap?

Tags: shower, faucet, hose, taps, adapter

I want to attach this shower hose attachment to my bathroom tap. It's a two-way system that lets you use the water through the tap or the shower head. Unfortunately the sizes don't match. The hose has M22 and M24 attachments, and the tap thread has a 2cm diameter.

- I've checked all the plumber and bathroom suppliers, and none have any adapters for this.
- I also cannot replace the tap since I'm renting.
- I have also looked into getting a different hose that would fit, and that does not exist either!

So the only option that's coming to my mind is to patch this to make it work somehow. Obviously permanent glue/epoxy is not an option either. So any suggestions or tips would be tremendously appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image: just about?!]
[image: tap’s original thread and nozzle]
[image: threads!]

[This](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/57609/imperial-to-metric-tap-thread-adapter) is a similar problem I previously had in another apartment, but now the size and the whole tap is different. Please see the photos there if it helps resolving any ambiguities.

Comment: Your problem is not that the thread on your tap is wrong - it's that your tap does not have any thread on it at all.

Comment: @brhans it does. See this post: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/155069/23441

Comment: Ok - then you should add a photo of that here instead of hoping someone will try to find that other question of yours. The photos you've put here don't show any thread on your tap.

Comment: @brhans I’ve explained that it has a 2cm diameter and threaded. I wasn’t hoping someone will try to find another post but was expecting the information I’ve provided would be taken granted. Added two more photos anyways.

Comment: It's inconceivable that no combination of adapters exists to allow the two threads to eventually be connected - you're not limited to only using a single adapter

Answer (score 1):

You have obviously tried to no avail at hardware stores and the like. Somewhere adapters are available but sometimes it's exhausting to locate them. There are rubberized couplings for small diameter pipe similar to rubber drain couplings.

Here's an example of a 3/4 inch one.

[image]

https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-4-in-x-3-4-in-PVC-Flexible-Coupling-P1056-075/100187989

Answer (score 0):

If you can determine the threads of the end of the faucet, that one piece of information will allow you to commission an adapter to be constructed. A machine shop would be able to build the adapter on a lathe, either CNC or manually, in short order, but it's likely to be expensive.

Another option is to use a 3D modeling program to design the adapter, based on the thread information and diameters required, then use an online service such as Shapeways to have the adapter 3D printed in metal.

None of these methods are particularly inexpensive, some are DIY if one has a lathe (unlikely in an apartment, I know) but you also would want to see if there are makerspaces in your area.

The comment regarding threads not present would apply if a photo of the inside showed only smooth metal, but I did not make that assumption.

I've used hose adapters for similar projects. It's a piece of thick walled rubber tubing with clamps at each end. Slid part way up the faucet pipe and tightened, the other end takes your threaded segment and is also clamped securely. Not particularly attractive, but quite functional and removable.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many, many aerator thread adapters available; in all different sizes. There most certainly exists the right one for you, you just have not found it yet.

I would travel to *a reputable and highly recommended* **plumbing shop** (note- a *plumbing shop* is distinctly different then either a "big-box" hardware supplier or a hardware store) . There you are likely to find a thread gauge specifically for aerators and spouts and a multitude of adapters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. This seems exactly like what I need. Unfortunately Ireland is such an odd island that what’s common or usual elsewhere is usually hard to find here. I tried the most reputable plumbing shops in Dublin and all they could say was: “what do you want this hose attachment for?” Followed by: “no, sorry about that, we don’t have such a thing”.

Comment: Could I get one of these online? I can’t seem to find it on Amazon.

Comment: You should be able to find something online, but you need to know the thread pitch of both sides as well as diameter of the pieces to be adapted. A plumber might be able to create one for you as well, with a small thick walled pvc pipe by using a die to create the desired sizes on each end.

Comment: Please note that 90% of the businesses that come up when you search for a plumbing supply company online, are not really plumbing supply companies.    Most just sell you stuff like faucets, showers, and baths.